# How to apply an ID to Shortcode Embedded iframe

Tags: shortcode, embed, youtube, oembed

I want to add an `id="myid"` to shortcode embedded iframe:-

```
$video_url = get_post_meta($post_id, 'video_url',true);
//or
$video_url .= 'video url';
$check_embeds=$GLOBALS['wp_embed']->run_shortcode( '[embed]'. $video_url .'[/embed]' );
echo $check_embeds;
```

This code helps me to display video through custom meta box just using a video url. And additionally I want add an ID to iframe here, example:-  `<iframe id="myid" src=""></iframe>`like this. 
Can anybody help me to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- Add this to your child theme's functions file:

```
add_filter("embed_oembed_html", function( $html, $url, $attr ) { 
    if ( !empty( $attr['id'] ) ) {
        $html = str_replace( "<iframe", sprintf( '<iframe id="%s"', $attr['id'] ), $html );
    }
    return $html;
}, 10, 3);
```

2.- Now use `[embed id="myid"]` applying the ID attribute in the shortcode.

```
$check_embeds=$GLOBALS['wp_embed']->run_shortcode(
    '[embed id="myid"]'. $video_url .'[/embed]'
);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're talking about using an `<iframe>` to embed the video URL, I decided to take a different approach instead of using WordPress' [`[embed]`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embed_Shortcode) shortcode and create my own `[iframe]` shortcode (add this to your `functions.php`):

```
add_shortcode( 'iframe', 'wpse_237365_iframe_shortcode' );

function wpse_237365_iframe_shortcode( $iframe ) {
    $tags = array( // Default values for some tags
        'width' => '100%',
        'height' => '450',
        'frameborder' => '0'
    );

    foreach ( $tags as $default => $value ) { // Add new tags in array if they don't exist
        if ( !@array_key_exists( $default, $iframe ) ) {
            $iframe[$default] = $value;
        }
    }

    $html = '<iframe';
    foreach( $iframe as $attr => $value ) { // Insert tags and default values if none were set
        if ( $value != '' ) {
            $html .= ' ' . esc_attr( $attr ) . '="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '"';
        }
    }
    $html .= '></iframe>';
    return $html;
}
```

#### Why not work off of the [embed] shortcode?

The code I provided above not only lets you add your `id=` attribute, but also any other attributes you plan on adding, giving you much more flexibility.

**Shortcode Example 1**

```
[iframe src="https://link.to/video" id="my-id-here" width="100%" height="500"]
```

Will give you:

```
<iframe src="https://link.to/video" id="my-id-here" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

**Shortcode Example 2**

You can even make up attributes if need be:

```
[iframe src="https://link.to/video" scrolling="yes" custom-tag="test"]
```

Will give you:

```
<iframe src="https://link.to/video" scrolling="yes" custom-tag="test" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```